# Laravel logout fail on pressing back button

Tags: php, laravel

On logout from my Laravel application using the Laravel logout method:

```
public function getLogout() 
    {
       Auth::logout();
       return Redirect::to('users/login')->with('message', '<div class="alert alert-success">Your have successfully logged out</div>');
    }
```

I am successfully logged out, but on hitting the back button, I can still access my account. Any idea on how I can fix this?

I am new to laravel, so I'm not sure if my question makes sense. Well in plain PHP, manually resetting the session to null has always done the job for me.

Comment: I think it's not a logout failure, but rather due to browser caching :/ Did you see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500848/browser-caching-after-logout) ?

Comment: See [how to edit header with Laravel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18101176/laravel-headers-and-caching-in-php)

Comment: You can still access your account **or** you can still view the cached page? What if you refresh after.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I solved it in Laravel 5 usign middleware:

Create a **NoCache** middleware like this:

Go through this: [How do I implement before vs. after filters in middleware?](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-5.0-middleware-filter-style#how-do-i-implement-before-vs.-after-filters-in-middleware)

```
class NoCache {
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        $response->headers->set('Cache-Control','nocache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate'); 
        $response->headers->set('Pragma','no-cache'); 
        $response->headers->set('Expires','Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT');
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Then register this middleware in kernel.php: [Running middleware on every request](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-5.0-middleware-filter-style#running-middleware-on-every-request)

Comment: It works like a charm, but can you explain what is it actually doing ? It will be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't actually what you think it is.

The back button on a browser fetches the last page in its cache for you.

If you must **really** prevent this, then you have two options:

1. Disable caching (usually a bad idea). See [How to control web page caching, across all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers) for that.
2. Have a JavaScript keep-alive to a resource in the page and redirect the user if this keepalive shows the user is not logged in.

Personally I'd just blame caching and ignore it. There's also a third option: using the HTML5 history API, but that's probably way over the top.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with this and it works.

In routes:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth', 'after' => 'no-cache'), function()
{
Route::get('dashboard', array('as' => 'getDashboard', 'uses' => 'DashboardController@getIndex'));

Route::get('logout', array('as' => 'getLogout', 'uses' => 'LoginController@getLogout'));

Route::group(array('prefix' => 'users'), function()
{
    Route::get('users', array('as' => 'getUsers', 'uses' => 'UsersController@getIndex', 'before' => 'hasAccess:users.index'));
});
});
```

In filters:

```
Route::filter('no-cache',function($route, $request, $response){

$response->headers->set('Cache-Control','nocache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
$response->headers->set('Pragma','no-cache');
$response->headers->set('Expires','Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT');

});
```

Comment: so basically for these routes, you are not caching. It looks like a good solution if you are not using much of images on your login page or dashboard. Otherwise the payload will be high

Answer (score 0):

Yes. As @Amelia wrote, that problem is because of browser cache but not Laravel. Sending response with no-cache is one solution, but that is not always good. You might have to pay a extra hosting fee if you implement that solution.

I tried to solve this issue with a bit of javascript code in my base template just before `</body>` tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var isAuth = "<?php echo Auth::check(); ?>";

        if (location.href === 'http://local.myapp.in/login/')
        {
            if (isAuth) location.href('/home');
        }
        else
        {
            if (!isAuth) location.href('/login');
        }
    });
</script>
```

In the above code, replace `http://local.myapp.in/login/` with your login page URL. So each time a page is loaded, this code gets executed. If the user is trying to access any restricted page without loggedin, then he will be redirected to login page. And if a user is trying to access `login` page when logged in, browser will be redirected to `home` page.

Since, it is js code, even if the page is loaded from browser cache this piece of code runs.

Comment: @enigmaticus Usually I write a base view and extend that view in all other views. Hence I had to write this code only in my base view.

Comment: hmm, I tried this and it is not working so I implemented something else, will post is soon

Answer (score 0):

Since I am new in Laravel. So in Laravel 5.7 I fixed that problem in my way.
Create a middleware using artisan.

```
php artisan make:middleware RevalidateBackHistory
```

Within RevalidateBackHistory middleware, we set the header to no-cache and revalidate.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
class RevalidateBackHistory
{
    /**
    * Handle an incoming request.
    *
    * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
    * @param \Closure $next
    * @return mixed
    */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        return $response->header('Cache-Control','nocache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate')
            ->header('Pragma','no-cache')
            ->header('Expires','Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT');
    }
}
```

Update the application’s route middleware in Kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    .
    .
    'revalidate' => \App\Http\Middleware\RevalidateBackHistory::class,
    .
    .
];
```

Update the route in Web.php. In my case.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'revalidate'], function(){
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'HomeController@index');
});
```

And that’s all! So basically you just need to call revalidate middleware for routes which require user authentication.

Here is the url's I followed

[Prevent Browser's Back Button Login After Logout in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30118998/prevent-browsers-back-button-login-after-logout-in-laravel-5)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wLkA1g2s65U