# Prevent Browser's Back Button Login After Logout in Laravel 5

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-5, logout

I am new to Laravel 5 and trying to make a simple authentication page. My problem is i can logout properly after i click to logout link but if i click to back button of the browser, still able to see the content of the page which actually should not be seen with respect to my auth middleware process. I read i can prevent this by disabling caching but don't think it is the best way to do this so how can i make this in a better way ? Simply my logout route is

```
Route::get('logout', array('uses' => 'LoginController@logout'));
```

Logout function is:

```
public function logout() {
        Auth::logout(); // logout user
        Session::flush();
        Redirect::back();
        return Redirect::to('pages/login'); //redirect back to login
}
```

Comment: can you show your code for logout and not only the route

Comment: if you want to clear cache have you tried Cache::flush()

Comment: @xenish check the edited question please, i have put it

Comment: This not an issue at all. Like @Wader mentioned below its just browser cached page. To verify this click back button and then try accessing pages the are protected

Comment: agree with @Digitlimit

Comment: @Digitlimit i already noticed that before i post this question but some important data can be seen when back button is clicked so i have to prevent this case. Thanks for advices though.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

When the user clicks the back button they're **not** actually logged in, its just the browser rendering what it has *cached* from previous page views. The user **won't** be able to navigate or interact with anything that requires them to be logged in because, to your application on the server, they're not authenticated.

When the user clicks the **back button** you have no control over that as **it doesn't make a request to the server**.

Using the back button, the only content they'll be able to view is that what they have already visited whilst logged in. If they try to access anything new, they'll make a new request to your application, your middleware will trigger and redirect them to the login page.

I guess if you really wanted to stop this behavior you could use some JavaScript and such to send an ajax request and check if the user is logged in that way, but quite useless from a security point of view.

Comment: Best explanation. :)

Comment: While this answer is good at explaining what is going on it doesn't really solve the problem. Say a user is looking at sensitive data, logs out, and walks away. Somebody else sits down at the computer and hits the back button. They will be able see the sensitive data. That seems like a huge security issue. I think one of the answers below about forcing a revalidation is more appropriate.

Answer (score 66):

Create a middleware using artisan:

```
php artisan make:middleware RevalidateBackHistory
```

Within RevalidateBackHistory middleware, we set the header to no-cache and revalidate:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
class RevalidateBackHistory
{
    /**
    * Handle an incoming request.
    *
    * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
    * @param \Closure $next
    * @return mixed
    */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        return $response->header('Cache-Control','nocache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate')
            ->header('Pragma','no-cache')
            ->header('Expires','Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT');
    }
}
```

Update the application’s route middleware in Kernel.php:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    .
    .
    'revalidate' => \App\Http\Middleware\RevalidateBackHistory::class,
    .
    .
];
```

And that’s all! So basically you just need to call revalidate middleware for routes which require user authentication.

Comment: @RaZik  I tested your solution, It's not working in Laravel 5.3.

Comment: This is a proper solution but I guest the bad side of this is we are discarding the cache that browsers maintain and all its benefits such as optimizing the loading time for users which will create slow sites and give the server more work. Laravel @taylorotwell FW should implement some way to avoid this if possible.

Comment: The solution is good but its affect the cache performance.. what if we want to use cache?

Comment: Optionally, if you want the middleware to run globally, add the class to $middleware in app/Http/Kernel.php.
If you only want it to run for web routes, add it to $middlewareGroups = ['web' => [

Answer (score 27):

Step 1 : create one middleware using following command:

```
php artisan make:middleware PreventBackHistory
```

Step 2:

replace content of PreventBackHistory.php with following content:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class PreventBackHistory
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        return $response->header('Cache-Control','no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate')
            ->header('Pragma','no-cache')
            ->header('Expires','Sun, 02 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT');
    }
}
```

step 3: register middleware in Kernel.php

```
'preventBackHistory' => \App\Http\Middleware\PreventBackHistory::class,
```

step 4: add 'preventBackHistory' to middleware protected routes in routes/web.php

```
Route::middleware(['preventBackHistory','otherMiddlewareClasses'])->group(function () {
```

Comment: step 4: use middleware in your controller's construstor

public function __construct()
    { 
        $this->middleware('preventBackHistory');
  $this->middleware('auth');
}

Comment: I like to apply this middleware to all authenticated routes in my routes file. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for this solution, this is still applicable on Laravel 10.

Answer (score 13):

A method I have used is to simply redirect to the previous page after logout.
So long as the previous page was secured, the auth middleware will kick in and redirect you back to the login page. Now when you click the back button the previous page is no longer cached and you just get the login page again.

Original discussion: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/back-button-browser

```
public function logout() {
        Auth::logout(); // logout user
        return redirect(\URL::previous());
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the user clicks back more than once

Comment: This is not a good method to do. As mentioned above, an infiltrator would most likely click back more than once (to view the cache). Thus this solution isn't a way to go. Unless you're just doing a quick fix

Answer (score 2):

Yeah its just a browser behavior, not any issue from laravel side but this could be a security issue. Here is how i solved it,

1. Create new middleware

> php artisan make: middleware PreventBackHistory

2. Replace middleware function handle

> ```
>     $response = $next($request);
>     $response->headers->set('Cache-Control','nocache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
>     $response->headers->set('Pragma','no-cache');
>     $response->headers->set('Expires','Sun, 02 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT');
>     return $response;
> ```

3. Include path in Kernal

> 'prevent-back-history' =>
> \App\Http\Middleware\PreventBackHistory::class

4. Update Routes

> Route::group(['middleware' =>
> ['prevent-back-history','otherMiddlewares']]

It will work for you!

Answer (score 1):

This question was considered resolved, but I'd like to put the solution I found and worked for me, since as explained by Jeff Adams in the comment below the selected answer, someone else might be able to see sensible information on the pages the user visited before logging out, big security concern in my opinion.

I am using apache so I added the following headers to my public/.htaccess:

- Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
- Header set Pragma "no-cache"
- Header set Expires 0

A more generic way would be to add the meta tags to your HTML:

- `<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />`
- `<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />`
- `<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />`

You can find what best fits your application here: https://cristian.sulea.net/blog/disable-browser-caching-with-meta-html-tags/

Comment: Could you update your answer with the relevant steps, then link to the blogpost as a reference? That way the information is preserved on SO even if the blog eventually goes offline.

Answer (score 1):

I know its an old question,

but there can be another approach as well.
Using the Middleware and solve the issue is logical but it will remove the cache of browser and that will have bad impact on the performance side.

So another approach is just to use a localstorage variable while login , set it as **1** then on the logout set it as **0** , On each page (the main layout is going to extend all our pages) check the localstorage value is **0** or not if its **0** redirect to login page.

In this way once user logout and press back button , the previous page will load and check the localstorage value and it again redirect back to login page. If you can put the checking script in top section of the page it will avoid the loading of that page as well.

```
 if(localStorage.getItem('loginstatus') == 0){
     document.location.href = "{{route('login')}}";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite logout method in your **AuthenticatesUsers** trait as:

```
public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $this->guard()->logout();
        $request->session()->invalidate();
        return $this->loggedOut($request) ?: redirect()->back();
    }
```

Comment: ya but its doesnot work on when site is hosted because you cant update vender after by hosting site its work only in your machine

Answer (score 0):

Using this `<a href={{$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}}>back</a>`
comes handy.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily log out using laravel "logout" route with post method ,

```js
const handleLogout = () => {
    axios.post('/logout')
        .then(() => location.href = '/home')
};
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: blade layout]

1. Add the PHP function session_start() to the top of layout.default blade file(make sure this code is placed at the top of every session required pages) as shown in the image.

Answer (score -1):

Try redirecting to a protected route with **auth** middleware:

```
return redirect('home');
```

so it will force redirect to the login page & the back button will not show the previous page