# How I Prevent Browser's Back Button Login After Logout

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-3

My problem is i can logout properly after i click to logout link but if i click to back button of the browser, still able to see the content of the page which actually should not be seen with respect to my auth middleware process.
I read i can prevent this by disabling caching but don't think it is the best way to do this so how can i make this in a better way ?MY Logout Function is

```
public function logout()
{
    Auth::logout();
    Session::flush();
    return redirect('login');
}
```

My Route Is:

```
Route::get('logout','Homecontroller@logout');
```

Thanx In advance

Comment: Actually what you see is cached, try to refresh the page after you go back using back button, you'll be redirected.

Comment: Yes But, some important data can be seen when back button is clicked so i have to prevent this case. Thanks for advices though.

Comment: I don't think there is a proper way to do it since it's a client side issue. Or that's what I understand from your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent Browser's Back Button Login After Logout in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30118998/prevent-browsers-back-button-login-after-logout-in-laravel-5)

Answer (score 12):

This problem is with the browser. The browser caches the content of the page and serves that cached content to the user when you are hitting the back button.

Set up cache-control meta tags on the pages that requires that a user is logged in. That way you are telling the browser not to cache it.

**E.g:**

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="private, max-age=0, no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
```

Comment: This solutions seems not working, Browser back button still move to dashboard page instead of login page :(

Comment: Putting these in the HEADERS of the response works for me.

Answer (score 2):

This javascript code worked for me:

```js
<script>
    // previous page should be reloaded when user navigate through browser navigation
    // for mozilla
    window.onunload = function(){};
    // for chrome
    if (window.performance && window.performance.navigation.type === window.performance.navigation.TYPE_BACK_FORWARD) {
        location.reload();
    }
</script>
```

Tested on Chrome Version 80.0.3987.122 (Official Build) (64-bit) and
Firefox 73.0.1 (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple AJAX request on top of your page (something like a ping service), set cache false and put some clause in it to redirect visitor to login if not authenticated.

So after logout, if you try to go back even if the main page is cached by the browser it will still try to load AJAX request back on page load. And since user authentication is not valid anymore it will redirect the user back to the login page.

Answer (score 0):

Add this javascript code, it will prevent redirect.

```
history.pushState(null, null, document.URL);
window.addEventListener('popstate', function () {
    history.pushState(null, null, document.URL);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a middleware using artisan

```
php artisan make:middleware RevalidateBackHistory
```

Within RevalidateBackHistory middleware, we set the header to no-cache and revalidate

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
class RevalidateBackHistory
{
    /**
    * Handle an incoming request.
    *
    * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
    * @param \Closure $next
    * @return mixed
    */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        return $response->header('Cache-Control','nocache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate')
            ->header('Pragma','no-cache')
            ->header('Expires','Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT');
    }
}
```

Update the application’s route middleware in Kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    .
    .
    'revalidate' => \App\Http\Middleware\RevalidateBackHistory::class,
    .
    .
];
```

And that’s all! So basically you just need to call revalidate middleware for routes which require user authentication.

Comment: Undefined method 'header'

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have already done with the Kernel and the Middleware

On your Controller, create a constructor, then add the middleware auth

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

I hope this work for you

Comment: This won't work as it works only when rendering serverside!