# Laravel - Browser displays message again when I press back button

Tags: php, laravel, session, materialize

Every time I create a new category in my application, it displays a message of success. Here is my code:

```
return redirect('dashboard/categorias')->with('message', 'Categoria criada com sucesso!');
```

I know it's not a big deal, but when I create a new category then I go to another page and press back button on browser, it shows the message again.

Here is my view:

```
@if(session('message'))
        <script>Materialize.toast('{{session('message')}}', 4000)</script>
        {{ Session::flush() }}

@endif
```

What should be done to not show this message again?

Comment: Have you tried flashing the session message? https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session#flash-data

Comment: back browser wont delete the session like that.try to things. first after seeing the success message refresh the page once then click back button, second after seeing the success message put the url of the page directly in the browser from where you are redirecting to success page

Comment: @linktoahref Yes, I tried it too, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Exprator I'm sorry, but whats the point of doing it? I want  to prevent users who use my application to see these kind of message twice, when they press back button. But thanks anyway.

Comment: i am just asking if you can see it or not. if not that means the session is not getting destroyed. you need to decrease this 4000 to something less like 1000

Comment: @Exprator I did both, it doesnt show the message again. Only when I submit the form, shows message for the first time, go to another link and then press back button, here it is, the message again :/

Comment: did you change the time from 4000 to 1000? and checked?

Comment: I can't do it, I need the toast to be shown for 4 seconds after submitting the form. But it can't be shown on back button.

Answer (score 6):

You should go for session flashing in laravel, once the session datat is read it is not available again:

```
$request->session()->flash('message', 'Categoria criada com sucesso!');
```

Or

```
Session::flash('message', 'Categoria criada com sucesso!');
```

**UPDATE**

Your issue seems to be of caching of the page,
use the following headers :

```
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

before sending out your response.

You can even create a middleware to not to use the cache, check the answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42057397/2952213

Comment: I tried both, they don't work. It keeps showing the message again when I press back button(left arrow on browser).

Comment: @GabrielFiel Please check the updated answer, That will help resolve your issue..

Comment: I'm sorry, but where am I suppose to add this code?

Comment: @GabrielFiel You ca simply add thin in your controller function where you flash your session or where you are displaying the page like so:
`public function someFunction()
{
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
return redirect('dashboard/categorias')->with('message', 'Categoria criada com sucesso!');
}`

Comment: It didn't work, I added on both store and update methods. :(

Comment: @GabrielFiel add it in the function that loads your page which you get when you press back button.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to update your code like :

```
@if(Session::has('message'))
        <script>Materialize.toast({{ Session::get('message') }}, 4000)</script>
        {{ Session::flush() }}

@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

add a few lines in your view

```
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

and after you display your message

```
@session()->forget('message');
```