# Strange Behaviour with Laravel - react Router and back Button

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, redux

I am building a weather app with laravel(almost finished) and i decided to implement the front end with react/redux/react-router and use laravel from api calls. The only thing that i decided to leave the same is my custom laravel auth implementation with routes and views. The way it works is: Authentication is controlled but laravel and when user logs in, is redirected to blade view (grouped by laravel auth middleware) from where react router takes control.

However i am facing an issue with back button. When navigating with react-router and hit the logout button(link that points to laravel logout route), the page redirects to welcome page like expected, but with back button returns to previous page where react-router and react components exist. But after, when i manually refresh the page, it redirects me to login page. (in summary everything works but i want somehow after logout to clear router history and not allow user to navigate back)

I saw many discussions about react-router and manipulating history but none worked.

Can someone help me?

Here is the code:

routes.php

```
Route::get('/', function (){
    return view('welcome');
})->middleware('guest');

Auth::routes();

Route::view('/dashboard', 'main')->middleware('auth');

Route::view('/categories', 'main')->middleware('auth');
```

main.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <title>
            ..
        </title>
        <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, 
          maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, shrink-to-fit=no'
          name='viewport' />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app_component"></div>
        <!--   Core JS Files   -->
        <script>
            window.Laravel = {!! json_encode([
            'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
            'apiToken' => auth()->user()->api_token ?? null,
        ]) !!};
        </script>
        <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

app.js (after imports)

```
if (document.getElementById('app_component')) {

    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + Laravel.apiToken;

    let store = configureStore();

    let jsx = (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <AppRouter/>
        </Provider>
    );

    let saveDataAndRenderApp = () => {
        ReactDOM.render(jsx, document.getElementById('app_component'))
    }

    store.dispatch(startCheckAuth()).then(()=>{      *** axios call
        store.getState().checkAuth.auth ?
            saveDataAndRenderApp()
            :
            store.dispatch(startLogoutUser()).then(()=>{
            location.assign('localhost/logout')
        })
    });
}
```

Approuter.js (after imports)

```
export const history = History();

class AppRouter extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <Router history={history}>
                <div className="wrapper">
                    <Sidebar/>
                    <div className="main-panel">
                        <Navbar/>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} exact/>
                            <Route path='/categories' component={Category} exact/>
                            <Route path='/create' component={Create} exact/>
                            <Route component={NotFound}/>
                        </Switch>
                    <Footer/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

export default connect()(AppRouter)
```

logout button inside Header component

```
    class NavbarUI extends React.Component {
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.logout = this.logout.bind(this)
        }
        logout(){
            this.props.dispatch(startLogoutUser()).then(()=>{
                location.assign('localhost/logout')  
            })
        }
        render() {
            return (
                <nav >...
<button onClick={this.logout}>Logout</button>              
                </nav>
            );
        }
    }

    export default withRouter(connect()(NavbarUI))
```

and action

```
let logoutUser = () => {
    return {
        type: 'LOGOUT'
    }
}

export let startLogoutUser = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return new Promise((resolve)=>{
            dispatch(logoutUser())
            resolve()
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42057397/9193055).

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! You saved my day. Lol i was searching for react solution or js. I wasn't thought that it could be solved with laravel :-D

Comment: "When navigating with react-router and hit the logout button(link that points to laravel logout route), the page redirects to welcome page like expected". In my case, this is what I want, so I am wondering how you got that. In my code, the logout actually reached the backend route (and page), but it can be only seen in React Devtools, while the browser still display the current React component. Now I see what I missed, I should add : location.assign that redirect to my expected login page. In my last project, I had to implement the login page using React, not Blade. Now I can choose both ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved creating a middleware in laravel, which prevents caching control and applied to every Route that i target a view with react-router implementation.

Maybe could be helpful for people combining react/react-router with laravel because someone may face the same situation.

Thanks a lot to Remul who commented me the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30118998/prevent-browsers-back-button-login-after-logout-in-laravel-5/42057397#42057397) !