# Session message repeat when click browser back

Tags: laravel, session, browser, back-button

I want to show a session message after login. i do it using this

```
@if ($message = Session::get('success'))
   <script>
       toastr.success('{{ $message }}');
   </script>
@endif
```

but when navigate another web page and click again browser back button . it shows previous session message . How can i remove session messages on browser back button.

I tried

```
{{ Session::forget('success') }}
```

it always forget session message. Even not display first time session.

Answer (score 1):

Its because of cache.

you can use headers before sending response

```
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

There is a answer that can help you
[prevent-browsers-back-button-login-after-logout-in-laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30118998/prevent-browsers-back-button-login-after-logout-in-laravel-5/42057397#42057397)

Comment: the problem is i am using cache to save some data and use it