# Prevent the browser back button to access pages after logout in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In my laravel application, I'm trying to avoid my users visiting a blade after the user logs out and press the browser back button.

So far  this is what  I've done,

I've created the following middleware(`preventBackHisory.php`)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PreventBackHistory
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        $response->headers->set('Cache-Control','nocache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
    
            $response->headers->set('Pragma','no-cache');
    
            $response->headers->set('Expires','Sun, 02 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT');
    
            return $response;
    }
}
```

Then in my `kernel.php` I added this in route middleware array,

```
'prevent-back-history' => \App\Http\Middleware\PreventBackHistory::class,
```

Finally, I changed my web.php to this

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['prevent-back-history','auth']], function() {
    Route::resource('/admins/roles','Admin\RoleController');
    Route::resource('/admins/users','Admin\UserController');
    Route::resource('/admins/participants','Admin\ParticipantController');
    Route::resource('/admins/inqueries','Admin\InqueryController');
    Route::patch('/admins/participants/{id}/edit/update', 'Admin\ParticipantController@update')->name('participants.update.update');
    Route::patch('/admins/participants/{id}/edit/update_tcp', 'Admin\TakeCarePersonController@update_tcp')->name('participants.update_tcp.update_tcp');
    Route::post('/admins/participants', 'Admin\ParticipantController@storetcp')->name('participants.storetcp');
    Route::post('/admins/participants/create', 'Admin\ParticipantController@store')->name('participants.store');
});
```

But still, I can go to the previous page once I'm logged out and press the browser back button...

Comment: If you setup a middleware that checks if the user is logged in, if they aren't, you redirect them back where they came from (for instance). I can already see you're using an `Auth` middleware, which should by default redirect you to a login page. Is that what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @n212 assume a user logs in to the dashboard and check his/her profile settings. Then user logs out from the site. So once the user logs out, he should not be able to view the previous profile settings blade if he clicks the browser back button.... but currently in my case even though the user logs out when he/she clicks on the back button still can see the previous content..

Comment: Yes, I see that. But the `Auth` middleware should already prevent that from happening. Have you checked that middleware to see if everything is right in that middleware?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30118998/prevent-browsers-back-button-login-after-logout-in-laravel-5

Comment: Try `no-cache` instead of `nocache`

Comment: as in the answers, i put <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" /> inside my head tags, and it worked.