# Do I need to clear local storage on the frontend if my laravel controller logout() is handling the logging out of a user?

Tags: php, laravel, debugging

I have a function in my controller that's supposed to log a user out.  It returns a success message upon clicking Logout on the frontend.  My question is, on the JS side, do I need to clear local storage?

I'm asking this because upon refreshing my page after a successful logout and landing on the login screen (when logging out, the user gets redirected from the dashboard to the login screen) - I get sent back to dashboard which to me indicates that my logout function isn't working as intended (or is it?).

Am I doing something wrong?

Here's my controller code:

```
public function logout(Request $request) {

    try {
        $this->_usersRepository->userLogout();
        $loggedOut = $this->_usersRepository->userLogout()->getStatusCode();

        if($loggedOut != 200) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Error while logging out!'], 500);
        }
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Successfully logged out',
            'loggedOut' => $loggedOut
        ]);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        Log::error($e->getMessage());
        throw new \Exception($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode(), $e);
    }

}
```

Respository code for deleting `oauth_access_tokens` in the DB:

```
public function userLogout() {
    DB::table('oauth_access_tokens')->where('user_id', Auth::id())->delete();
    return response()->json(['message' => 'User successfully signed out'], 200);
}
```

Comment: When the user clicks the back button they're not actually logged in, its just the browser rendering what it has cached from previous page views. The user won't be able to navigate or interact with anything that requires them to be logged in because, to your application on the server, they're not authenticated. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30119257/984422

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent Browser's Back Button Login After Logout in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30118998/prevent-browsers-back-button-login-after-logout-in-laravel-5)