# In my Laravel application I want to disabled browser back button?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am having number of pages after user login .I want to disabled browser back button.
I have tried prevent Back Middleware in Laravel for cache clear but when I am using this middleware its prevent me to login again it showing me 419 error.

Can anyone please help me to resolved this.

Comment: I think you need to add more validation in back-end and check for valid data, Never trust user input. If you are trying to disable back button it won't serve the purpose. User can open link in new tab and login. In this case user won't need to use the back-button to get old page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent Browser's Back Button Login After Logout in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30118998/prevent-browsers-back-button-login-after-logout-in-laravel-5)